# Encapsulating and reading into an array from text file

Tags: php, arrays, file-io, encapsulation

I'm trying to make 2 classes, to encapsulate these text files, Customer.txt and Orders.txt. The customer one I need to read each line into a separate instance of an array for each line of text, how can I do this?
Also, do I have to do something about the comma's in the text files?

I know I need to use fopen, just not sure how to go about doing it.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
<?php



class readOrders{

$array_of_lines = fopen("orders.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
  foreach($array_of_lines as $line) {
 $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line); 

}

class readCustomers{
$array_of_more_lines = fopen("customers.txt", 'r') or die("Failed to create file");
  foreach($array_of_more_lines as $line) {
 $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line);

}


?>
```

Here are my text files

Orders.txt

```
1,4,0133360903,Building Java Programs,Computer Science
2,6,0321836995,Mathematics All Around,Mathematics
3,24,0321825721,Mathematics for Elementary Teachers with Activity Manual,Mathematics
4,10,0133011208,Business Math,Business
```

customers.txt

```
2,Leonie,Köhler,leonekohler@surfeu.de,University of Stuttgart,Theodor-Heuss-Straße 34,Stuttgart,,Germany,70174,+49 0711 2842222
3,Bjørn,Hansen,bjorn.hansen@yahoo.no,University of Oslo,Ullevålsveien 14,Oslo,,Norway,0171,+47 22 44 22 22
4,François,Tremblay,ftremblay@gmail.com,McGill University,1498 rue Bélanger,Montréal,QC,Canada,H2G 1A7,+1 (514) 721-4711
```

Comment: `$array_of_lines = file('Orders.txt');` then `foreach($array_of_lines as $line) { $pieces_of_line = explode(',', $line); }`

Comment: What does explode do?

Comment: The best answer you will get from PHP when you will begin to try to run your code and see the results. If you get errors you must try to correct code youself, seeing examples and googling error messages. At least if you cannot resolve your problem You may ask help here. Returns to your question - where do you get your data from?  - If there is an application that exports csv and not control data then I advice you to use fgetcsv. If you are sure that comma will be as delimiter of fields only and comma will not be inside data - you can use the first decision as simplest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **fgetcsv** will be useful here, example from php-doc:

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```